# xmlhttprequest recognize as pop-up

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, popup

I have an issue, with that code with my xmlhttprequest code.
The aim is to execute mac.php every 10 seconds but when I go to my webpage, the first time, it will block all pop-up (mac.php) even if mac.php is not a pop-up !
I reload the page and now it is not recognize as a pop-up !!
I would like to know why it is recognise as a pop-up some time and other not.

Thanks

Here's my code :

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function mac() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            xmlhttp.responseText;
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "mac.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    mac();
    setInterval(mac, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Can I see your mac.php file

Comment: <?php
    $ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $macAddr="";
    #run the external command, break output into lines
    $arp=`arp -a $ipAddress`;
    $lines=explode(" ", $arp);
    $macAddr=$lines[3];
    echo exec("echo $macAddr > clients/$macAddr");
    ?>

Comment: It just creates a file with the mac address of the client in the folder "client"

Comment: What browser are you using? This seems like strange behaviour.

Comment: I used Frefox and Chrome and I have this bug for both...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. Try changing "mac.php" to "http://whatever-your-page-is.com/mac.php" - obviously changing the url to your site's. The message about pop-up blocking may be browser specific.

Comment: well, they could be running this locally, or the browser they are using might be directly matching the urls so that `//foo.com !== http://foo.com`. I find with XMLHttpRequest it's best to be sure.

Comment: I try to change the path, but it doesn't solve my problem, it leads to an other one. Rather than be recognize as a pop-up, it redirect my page to my mac.php (which is a blank page because there is no output)

Comment: Something in the page you are not showing is causing this issue